# How to use @ColorInt

Tags: android, colors

How to use `@ColorInt int` to declare a 32 bits unsigned color value?

When I use it I get a `Cannot find symbol class ColorInt` at build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are probably missing the dependency. Add

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
```

to your `build.gradle`, in the dependency section. Alternatively you can use the  `Project Structure Dialog`, select the module, and go to the "`dependency`" section. There click on `+` and then "library dependency". From there you can select `support-annotations`

Comment: And how to cast it? `@ColorInt int color = () Long.decode("0xFF583530")`

Comment: I found: `@ColorInt int color = Color.parseColor("#ffd9ff04");`